# Importing javascript library works in chrome but not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 and I'm trying to import some javascript libraries as jquery, bootstrap.js and some more. It's working fine in Chrome but not in IE 11.

Can anyone see what I am missing?

BundleConfig:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/EventReader.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.floatThead.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.floatThead.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "~/Content/EventReader.css"));
    }
```

_Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")


</head>
<body>
<div class="container body-content">
@RenderBody()
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my View(Index):

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<title>Index</title>

</head>
<body>
</body>
```

In IE11 I get following Errors:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' (jquery-2.1.4.js).
Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener' (jquery-2.1.4.min.js)
Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery (bootstrap.js)
```

Comment: @RenderBody() gets the content from your View(Index.cshtml), so no need to declare html, head, title, meta and body tags in your view. Just declare the content.

Comment: @Dandy Thanks, but it didn't help

Comment: What do you get when you view source in IE11, do you see script tags in the html source?

Comment: @Dandy Yes, I can see them in the head tag. First jquery, Jquery.Min, unobtrusive-ajax, and so on...

Comment: if you open IE debug tools (press F12), and dont see any javascript errors in 'Console' window, then i guess everything is working fine.

Comment: @krillezzz what do you mean by "It's working fine in Chrome but not in IE 11"? What's the problem you're observing?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have updated with errors. In IE jquery doesnt seem to load correctly

Comment: @krillezzz try adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"> just after <meta charset="utf-8" /> in your _layout.cshtml file.

Comment: @Dandy Thanks! Please write as answer and so I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">` in document head section
to force IE to render with the latest IE version's standard.